# How to uninstall a software that has a bug in the uninstaller?

Tags: windows, installation, uninstall, windows-installer

The bug causes the unistaller to rollback the uninstallation.
How can I force the software removal?
The "installer" is a MSI package.

Comment: What's the software? If it's a known issue there might be information already out on the web about it.

Comment: It's mine. I haven't published it yet.

Comment: You might want to test installation and such on virtual machines; that way, you don't have a problem if you can't uninstall cleanly.

Comment: Great idea David!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) works great!  It has three different modes for scanning for related files.  It removes things that other uninstallers miss.

Comment: It worked for me, when everything else failed. It just removed some registry entries though.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to `Repair` the installation and then `Uninstall`

Comment: But later I ran into similar problems that weren't solved so simply